# Change TabViewItem Header Fontsize

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, tabview

in my case it seems that the font size for the **TabView** **header** object is not changeable.

#### Source Code

```
               <controls1:TabViewItem Header="Document" Height="31" Width="476">
```

#### Question

How do I change the font size of the Header object?

Comment: You can't change its fontsize through TabViewItem FontSize property or Tabview FontSize property, you need to modify its style default resource.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following steps to change the fontsize of TabViewItem header.

1.Open **Document Outline**->right click the **TabViewItem** -> **Edit a template**->**Edit a copy**

Here you will see a ControlTemplate which key is TabViewItemTemplate1.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TabViewItemTemplate1" TargetType="muxc:TabViewItem">
…
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderForeground}" FontSize="25" HighContrastAdjustment="None" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
…
</ControlTemplate>
```

As you can see, there is a `ContentPresenter` named ContentPresenter, which controls the fontsize of the Header of TabViewItem. So you could change the `Fontsize` property, as shown the above, I changed fontsizew to 25.

2.Then you could use `TabViewItemTemplate1` as the template of TabViewItem, as follows:

```
 <muxc:TabView>          
     <muxc:TabViewItem Template="{StaticResource TabViewItemTemplate1}" Header="Home"  /> 
     <muxc:TabViewItem Header="Item1"/>
     <muxc:TabViewItem Header="Item2"/>
 </muxc:TabView>
```